# How to pad an ArrayBuffer to a multiple of 4?

Tags: javascript

I'm using the new FileReader API to read in a file as an [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ArrayBuffer). I then create a "view" into that ArrayBuffer via [UInt32Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Uint32Array) to work with another API.

The problem is that my files aren't necessarily multiples of 4 bytes, and Chrome throws an error ("Uncaught RangeError: bofyshould be a multiple ofe") when I try to feed `Uint32Array` a bad multiple. So how can I pad the `ArrayBuffer` with 0s so that it becomes a multiple?

```
var reader = new FileReader();
var pos = 0;
var xxh = XXH();

reader.onprogress = function(progress) {
    // round down length to the nearest multiple of 4, save the remaining bytes for the next iteration
    var length = Math.floor((progress.loaded - pos)/Uint32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT);
    var arr = new Uint32Array(reader.result, pos, length);
    pos += length * Uint32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT;
    xxh.update(arr);
};

reader.onload = function() {
    // `pos` will be a multiple of 4 here but the number of remaining bytes might not be. How can I pad `reader.result`?
    var arr = new Uint32Array(reader.result, pos); // error occurs here
    xxh.update(arr);
};

reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use Uint8Array instead, as it have byte precision. If you need to access the data with other types different than unsigned byte, create a DataView : `new DataView(arr.buffer)`

```
reader.onprogress = function(progress) {
    var arr = new Uint8Array(reader.result, pos, length);
    xxh.update(arr);
};

reader.onload = function() {
    var arr = new Uint8Array(reader.result, pos);
    xxh.update(arr);
};
```